# Compiling printf() without including <stdio.h>

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

How msvc11 can compile `printf("msvc");` with only `<iostream>` header?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    printf("test123");
    cin.get();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

No error...

msvc11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2013, `iostream` includes `istream` which includes `ostream` which includes `ios` which includes `xlocnum` which includes `cstdio` which includes `stdio.h`. It's just standard header file spill-over.

Comment: Looks like g++ on the mac does the same thing, iostream->ostream->ios->bits/c++locale.h->cstdio->stdio.h

Comment: Hehe ok thank you but is this only for visual studio 2013?, if so how can i disable it?

Comment: @user2400925 as far as I can tell, you can't. I don't have a copy of the standard handy, but the VC header file automatically brings `std::printf` into the global namespace with a `using` directive.